# Probablity of finding A or B or both A and B

Tags: probability

In a jungle, the probability of an animal being a mammal is 0.6, a nocturnal is 0.2. What is the probability that an animal found in this jungle is either a mammal, or nocturnal or both. Assume that these are independent traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability that $A$, $B$, or both $A$ and $B$ occur is
$$
P(A\text{ and }B)+P(A\text{ and not }B)+P((\text{not }A)\text{ and }B).
$$

Answer (score 0):

**A different hint:** The probability that $A$, $B$, or both $A$ and $B$ occur is
$$\begin{align}
P(A \mathbin{\operatorname {or}} B) &= 1 - P(\operatorname{not} (A \mathbin{\operatorname{or}} B)) \\
&= 1-P((\operatorname{not}A) \mathbin{\operatorname{and}}(\operatorname{not}B)).
\end{align}$$

The second equality follows from De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the general formula for the union of two events: $P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$. Now use the fact that the sample space is equal to $S = B \cup B^c$. Since $B$ and $B^c$ are disjoint, you can write $P(A) = P(AB) + P(AB^c)$. Likewise, $P(B) = P(AB) + P(A^c B)$. Thus,

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
P(A \cup B) & = & P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) \\
& = & P(AB) + P(AB^c) + P(AB) + P(A^c B) - P(AB) \\
& = & P(AB) + P(AB^c) + P(A^c B) \\
& = & P(B) P(A|B) + P(AB^c) + P(A^c B) \\
& = & P(A) P(B) + P(AB^c) + P(A^c B)
\end{array}
$$

where we used $P(AB) = P(B) P(A|B) = P(A) P(B)$ since they are given to be independent.